# group by order by match against

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, match, match-against

I want use ORDER BY and GROUP BY on the same query. But If I use Group BY the relevance don't work correctly.

This is the code:

```
(SELECT *, MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('$busqueda') AS relevancia 
FROM libros 
WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('$busqueda') AND tipo = 'nuevo'
GROUP BY id_libro 
ORDER BY relevancia DESC, posicion ASC, precio DESC LIMIT $numero_limite)
```

If I get make the equivalente of this (another example) but with the previous code my query will works correctly, because on this example the order by and the group by works good, but not have the match against that I need:

```
SELECT
   t.id, t.catid, t.name, t.userid, t.subject  
FROM
    (SELECT id,  catid,  name,  userid,  subject , thread
    FROM mensajes
    ORDER BY t.id DESC) t
GROUP BY t.thread  
LIMIT 6;
```

This is the table (Sorry, the forum does not let me put pictures to not have 10 points):

http://www.forosdelweb.com/f86/group-match-against-respetando-relevancia-1089769/#post4561689

You can see the captures/Images on that link.

As you can see on the image 3, the result is incorrect. Must be the id_unico 9, because have a posicion 21.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Can you provide a working demonstration? - although, in the absence of any aggregating functions one wonders why you're *grouping* at all

Comment: To further @Strawberry's comment, why would `id_libro` have duplicate values in `libros`?

Comment: At this moment I can't put a working demonstration. I have duplicate values in libros because "id_libro" is not the primary key, is like a ISBN, but that book can be on a lot of providers and I want ORDER BY relevancia, posicion, precio... The results.

Comment: * I modified the above message, adding another example code.

Comment: *At this moment I **can't** put a working demonstration.* Why? What is holding you back? All you need is to spend less than a minute to grab some rows that produce duplicate results and post it in your question. What can be simpler?

Comment: Now I update 3 images with the problem (visit the link).

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is simply wrong.  It is using an extension to `group by` in MySQL that is explicitly documented to return arbitrary column values, not the values that your query requires.  You can read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).

You can do what you want by finding the maximum relevancia using a subquery, as in:

```
select l.*
from (SELECT *, MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('$busqueda') AS relevancia 
      FROM libros l
      WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('$busqueda') AND tipo = 'nuevo'
     ) l
where not exists (select 1
                  from libros l2
                  where l2.id_libros = l.id_libros and
                        l2.tipo = l1.typo and
                        MATCH(l2.keywords) AGAINST('$busqueda') > l.relevancia
                 )

ORDER BY relevancia DESC, posicion ASC, precio DESC
LIMIT $numero_limite;
```

Comment: As an Oracle developer, I didn't know about that MySQL extension. It seem like it could be very useful but also potentially very dangerous... yet it seems to be enabled by default.

Comment: Your code (changing the 12.tipo = 'neuvo' --> nuevo) don't work, show me an error. I don't understand.

Comment: @Gordon-Linoff, Now, I removed this part: "and l2.tipo = 'neuvo'" and this AND tipo = 'nuevo'... And the code don't show any error but show duplicate id_libros. I need unique id_libros...